# How to design a Map application with Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, leaflet

So I want to build a map application with backbone(probably using Leaflet.js). I have a few ideas on how to design this, and I was wondering if there was a common design pattern on how to do this.

The map will eventually be integrated with other visualizations - for example if I select a marker on the map something will happen in another visualization. I must also be able to conduct geo-searches on the markers in the map.

There are two ways I thought of doing this -

1.Have a backbone model per marker, have a collection of markers, have a Map View that works on this collection. So whenever this collection changes, re-render the map.

2.Have a model called MapModel that holds json, and have a data function that filters the json (based on a geosearch or something). The Map then simply renders this json.

The advantage of 1 is that I think it would be easy to do selections, but as my map may deal with tens of thousands, to hundreds of thousands of objects, I feel like things would be very very slow.

Is there another way to do this, or which one of the two ideas I've had is preferable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on exactly the same problem, I do not claim to have found a "common design pattern", but I can tell you what I did.

I created a MapModel which contains the info necessary to make the map: for instance a collection of stores if you want to put stores on your map.

Then I created a View of the map with no collection of markers: the problem is that a group of markers in leaflet is supposed to be grouped in a L.LayerGroup class (for instance to control when they are added or removed - [example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html)). So it feels very clumsy to have the markers in a LayerGroup and in a collection disguised as models.

So I created a layerGroup holding all the markers, this layer being a property of the MapView. If your app is complex, you may even create a subView for each layer.

When you want to filter you filter on the model, which is easy since it's a backbone collection, then you render the View.

> my map may deal with tens of thousands, to hundreds of thousands of objects

That's problematic. It's impossible to place such a huge number of markers on webmap, you should plan how to deal with it ([a popular plugin](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster))